# Python - (better text editor integration) changing the default stacktrace format displayed in the terminal

Tags: python, terminal, stack-trace

Let's take a typical stacktrace running Python on the command line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load_mvprd.py", line 654, in <module>
    run()
  File "/myapp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
...
  File "load_mvprd.py", line 172, in __init__
    self.di = self.loadyaml(section_stepnames.bme_load)
  File "load_mvprd.py", line 124, in loadyaml
    return di[section]
KeyError: 'bme_load'
```

I am on OSX, using **iTerm2** which allows you to click on stuff and launch a matching command (typically, what's been associated with the file extension).

#### this open the file, but just at the top, or leaves the cursor where it is if it's already open:

[image]

This is nice, I can launch my editor right from here, and Sublime will open my file.

However... if instead of `"load_mvprd.py", line 124`, I just had `"load_mvprd.py":124`,

then Sublime would open the file at line 124.

- Visual Studio Code -  requires `code -g "load_mvprd.py:124"`
- Vim `vim +124 ""load_mvprd.py"`

These might be more difficult to get working, but I assume it could be done.

I realize you can format the stack output within a Python program.  However, is there a way to change the default representation of the file name and line number so that one can open the file right from the terminal?

#### What I want:

this will open the file right at line 124 and will move the editor to line 124 there if it's already open.

[image]

#### And in Visual Studio's own terminal, this also opens at line 124:

(the trick there is to start the line as a file path)

[image]

Comment: Set `sys.excepthook` to an appropriate `traceback`-wielding function?